# RTP Audio on FFMPEG for IOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I have successfully compiled ffmpeg for ios and installed it on the device, however when i run the program on ios it does not work....these are the parameters i passed to ffmpeg on ios

```
int ffmpegInit()
{
    int64_t ti;

    char **argv=malloc(14*sizeof(char*));

    for (int i=0; i<14; i++) {

        argv[i]=malloc(1024);
    }

    int argc=13;

    argv[1]="-f";
    argv[2]="g722";
    argv[3]="-i";
    argv[4]="default";
    argv[3]="-ar";
    argv[4]="16000";
    argv[5]="-acodec";
    argv[6]="g722";
    argv[7]="-ab";
    argv[8]="64k";
    argv[9]="-ac";
    argv[10]="1";
    argv[11]="-f";
    argv[12]="rtp";
    argv[13]="rtp://127.0.0.1:1234";
```

This code is not working properly on ios.....what are the right arguments to pass on ios(for rtp) and does ios allow such an option to pass parameters to ffmpeg. Please let me know your comments.
Thanks,
Vikram.